# Inserting a new key value in a JSON document

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Json document like this..

```
{
"Name":"SSS",
"Condition":"good",
"Flows":[
         {
          "Date":"2018-07-13",
          "Formulae":{
                       "less":"4",
                       "more":"5"
                      }
         },
         {
          "Date":"2018-07-14",
          "Formulae":{
                      "team":"4",
                       "nature":"3"
                      }
          }
   ]
}
```

I want to insert the new key,value("flat":"4")after the "more":"5" inside the document based on "Name":"SSS", "Date":"2018-07-13".
My desired output is

```
"name":sss",
"condition":"good",
"flows":[
         {
          "Date":"2018-07-13",
          "Formulae":{
                       "less":"4",
                       "more":"5",
                       "flat":"4" 
                      } 
          },
         {
          "Date":"2018-07-14",
          "Formulae":{
                      "team":"4",
                       "nature":"3"
                      }
          },
]
}
```

Comment: What is the issue are you facing ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide the code you have and point out the exact location, where you have trouble? Can you provide a specific description of the problem you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this mongo command, to translate in java :

```
db['01'].update(
  {"Name":"SSS","Flows":{$elemMatch:{Date:"2018-07-13"}}},
  {$set:{"Flows.$.Formulae.flat":4}}
)
```